# How to fix "Method findViewById must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker thread less"

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I am working on layout inflater for designing multiple JSON array insted of using nested listview,How Can i set inflater for multiple array response from json?

I have used layout inflater method

```
Layout inflater =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_text_room, null);
TextView homeId=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.homeId);
```

I expect text view should be create but i got error like Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Comment: please put code. where you put that line in your code that depends most probably runOnUiThread() will get the job done but gotta see your code that whether this will work or not

Comment: if your activity_text_room layout have same textview id "homeId"

Comment: @dipali Please share code fragment which is giving error with logs .

Comment: list_value.addView(view); list_value is linearl ayout of parent xml @Urvishrana

Comment: Provide the complete code of java file

Comment: The answer is **literally** in your question's title.

Comment: i am using layout inflater for set data from json but got error

Comment: @dipali put your code in question section

Answer (score 0):

In Android views cannot be changed in any other thread than the main UI thread. Depending on your code you might want to:

1. use [runOnUIThread method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) of your Activity
2. Use AsyncTask class, its onPostExecute method is run in the UI thread.